# Linear Algebra, geometric multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix and the question says I that I have an eigenvalue of 0.
 The question asks me to find the geometric multiplicity of that eigenvalue. I know the answer      is 4. I just don't understand how it is 4 since this matrix can be reduced to just one row of `1 1 1 1 1`and the rest of the rows are 0's. Thanks in advance for your comments/

```
  1 1 1 1 1 
  1 1 1 1 1
  2 2 2 2 2
  2 2 2 2 2
  2 2 2 2 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ for the $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is, by definition, the dimension of the subspace
$$
E_A(\lambda)=\{v\in K^n:Av=\lambda v\}
$$
where $K$ is the base field, in your case probably $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and the elements of $K^n$ are column vectors.

This subspace is just the null space (also known as kernel) of the matrix $A-\lambda I_n$, because
$$
Av=\lambda v
\quad\text{if and only if}\quad
Av=\lambda I_nv
\quad\text{if and only if}\quad
(A-\lambda I_n)v=0
$$

The dimension of this subspace is computed easily:
$$
\dim E_A(\lambda)=\dim N(A-\lambda I_n)=n-\operatorname{rank}(A-\lambda I_n)
$$
by the rank-nullity theorem.

The case of $\lambda=0$ is no different:
$$
\dim E_A(0)=\dim N(A-0I_n)=\dim N(A)=n-\operatorname{rank}(A)
$$
and in your case $n=5$ and $\operatorname{rank}(A)=1$.

Comment: Very clear thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, *precisely because* you can reduce your matrix to that is that the geometric multiplicity of zero is four...

Think it this way: you're looking for the dimension of the solution subspace of the homogeneous linear system whose coefficients' matrix is your matrix, so getting only one
 non-zero row after reducing the matrix means you have $\;4\;$ degrees of freedom to choose your general solution vector...voila!

Comment: Let me know if I am understanding this correctly, so because we have reduced our matrix by 4 rows, our geometric multiplicity is 4?I never learned about degrees of freedom in linear, I should look that up thanks.

Comment: @MichelTamer, you studied linear systems, right? Did you study the set of solutions of a **homogeneous* linear system of equations is a vector subspace of the corresponding space?

Comment: Yes I have, it is when you have a set of equations with similar variables and you are trying to figure out what the variables are.

Comment: @MichelTamer And the homogeneous case is when you equate the equations to zero, which is the same as looking as the dimension of the eigenspace of the eigenvalue zero of your matrix... *exactly the same*